# Inserting data in Hive table in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-storage

I need to insert data in hive table in Windows Azure. I have googled it but not sure where to begin.
Please tell me from where I should start. 
Please provide any link (if possible).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

- [Sqoop Import-Export Sample](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/howto-run-samples/sample-sqoop-import-export/)
- [Upload data to HDInsight](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/howto-upload-data-to-hdinsight/)
- [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables)